# How can I run Keras, tensorflow program in background and leave all logs?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, terminal, keras

I used `nohup` for running my `Keras, Tensorflow` program in background.

This is how I run the program :

```
>> nohup python my_program.py  &> log.txt  &
```

But when I opened `log.txt` after a while, it only contains:

```
nohup: ignoring input
2017-08-23 09:44:54.100172: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-23 09:44:54.100212: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-23 09:44:54.100219: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-23 09:44:54.228996: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-08-23 09:44:54.229641: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80
major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.8235
pciBusID 0000:00:04.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.09GiB
2017-08-23 09:44:54.229661: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
2017-08-23 09:44:54.229667: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
2017-08-23 09:44:54.229675: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0)
```

I hope that this file contains all output of my program, including `print()`.

How can I do this?

- `OS : Linux Ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: Are you actually interested in the logs, or in the program results (e.g. progress of train/val accuracy etc)?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using nohup to run my deep learning codes too. If you just run

```
> nohup python my_program.py &
```

all the output, including the `print`s, will be writed in the default file `nohup.out`.

In my case, in addition to that, I have created a function which is called after the model ends the training, and stores all the information present in the `history` object returned by the `fit_generator` method.

Comment: I often output new cool results into a "cloud" directory, so that can check results once in a while when I'm away.

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me

```
nohup python my_program.py > log.txt  &
```

If you have any parameters to `my_program.py`, you can pass it before `>` as shown below

```
nohup python my_program.py --xyz 0 > log.txt  &
```